# Delphi - Message pump in thread not receiving WM_COPYDATA messages

Tags: multithreading, delphi, wm-copydata

I'm trying (in D7) to set up a thread with a message pump, which eventually I want to transplant into a DLL.

Here's the relevant/non-trivial parts of my code:

```
const
  WM_Action1 = WM_User + 1;
  scThreadClassName = 'MyThreadClass';

type
  TThreadCreatorForm = class;

  TWndThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTitle: String;
    FWnd: HWND;
    FWndClass: WNDCLASS;
    FCreator : TForm;
    procedure HandleAction1;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreator: TForm; const Title: String); 
  end;

  TThreadCreatorForm = class(TForm)
    btnCreate: TButton;
    btnAction1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    btnQuit: TButton;
    btnSend: TButton;
    edSend: TEdit;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAction1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnQuitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMAction1(var Msg : TMsg); message WM_Action1;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    WndThread : TWndThread;
    ThreadID : Integer;
    ThreadHWnd : HWnd;
  end;

var
  ThreadCreatorForm: TThreadCreatorForm;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure SendStringViaWMCopyData(HSource, HDest : THandle; const AString : String);
var
  Cds : TCopyDataStruct;
  Res : Integer;
begin
  FillChar(Cds, SizeOf(Cds), 0);
  GetMem(Cds.lpData, Length(Astring) + 1);
  try
    StrCopy(Cds.lpData, PChar(AString));
    Res := SendMessage(HDest, WM_COPYDATA, HSource, Cardinal(@Cds));
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Res));
  finally
    FreeMem(Cds.lpData);
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadCreatorForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(Self.Handle, Nil);
  Assert(ThreadID = MainThreadID);
end;

procedure TWndThread.HandleAction1;
begin
  //
end;

constructor TWndThread.Create(ACreator: TForm; const Title:String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FTitle := Title;
  FCreator := ACreator;
  FillChar(FWndClass, SizeOf(FWndClass), 0);
  FWndClass.lpfnWndProc := @DefWindowProc;
  FWndClass.hInstance := HInstance;
  FWndClass.lpszClassName := scThreadClassName;
end;

procedure TWndThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
  Done : Boolean;
  S : String;
begin
  if Windows.RegisterClass(FWndClass) = 0 then Exit;
  FWnd := CreateWindow(FWndClass.lpszClassName, PChar(FTitle), WS_DLGFRAME, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, nil);
  if FWnd = 0 then Exit;

  Done := False;
  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) and not done do begin
    case Msg.message of
      WM_Action1 : begin
        HandleAction1;
      end;
      WM_COPYDATA : begin
        Assert(True);
      end;
      WM_Quit : Done := True;
      else begin
        TranslateMessage(msg);
        DispatchMessage(msg)
      end;
    end; { case }
  end;
  if FWnd <> 0 then
    DestroyWindow(FWnd);
  Windows.UnregisterClass(FWndClass.lpszClassName, FWndClass.hInstance);
end;
```

Once I've created the thread, I find its window handle using FindWindow and that works fine.

If I *PostMessage* it my user-defined WM_Action1 message, it's received by the GetMessage(), and caught by the case statement in the thread's Execute, and that works fine.

If I send myself (i.e. my host form) a WM_CopyData message using the SendStringViaWMCopyData() routine that works fine.

However:  If I send my thread the WM_CopyData message, the GetMessage and case statement in Execute never see it and the SendMessage in SendStringViaWMCopyData returns 0.

So, my question is, why does the WM_CopyData message not get received by the GetMessage in .Execute?  I have an uncomfortable feeling I'm missing something ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WM_COPYDATA` is not a **posted** message, it is a **sent** message, so it does not go through the message queue and thus a message loop will never see it.  You need to assign a window procedure to your window class and process `WM_COPYDATA` in that procedure instead.  Don't use `DefWindowProc()` as your window procedure.

Also, when sending `WM_COPYDATA`, the `lpData` field is expressed in **bytes** not in **characters**, so you need to take that in to account.  And you are not filling in the `COPYDATASTRUCT` correctly.  You need to provide values for the `dwData` and `cbData` fields. And you don't need to allocate memory for the `lpData` field, you can point it to your `String`'s existing memory instead.

Try this:

```
const
  WM_Action1 = WM_User + 1;
  scThreadClassName = 'MyThreadClass';

type
  TThreadCreatorForm = class;

  TWndThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTitle: String;
    FWnd: HWND;
    FWndClass: WNDCLASS;
    FCreator : TForm;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure HandleAction1;
    procedure HandleCopyData(const Cds: TCopyDataStruct);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure DoTerminate; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreator: TForm; const Title: String); 
  end;

  TThreadCreatorForm = class(TForm)
    btnCreate: TButton;
    btnAction1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    btnQuit: TButton;
    btnSend: TButton;
    edSend: TEdit;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAction1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnQuitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMAction1(var Msg : TMsg); message WM_Action1;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    WndThread : TWndThread;
    ThreadID : Integer;
    ThreadHWnd : HWnd;
  end;

var
  ThreadCreatorForm: TThreadCreatorForm;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

var
  MY_CDS_VALUE: UINT = 0;

procedure SendStringViaWMCopyData(HSource, HDest : HWND; const AString : String);
var
  Cds : TCopyDataStruct;
  Res : Integer;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Cds, SizeOf(Cds));
  Cds.dwData := MY_CDS_VALUE;
  Cds.cbData := Length(AString) * SizeOf(Char);
  Cds.lpData := PChar(AString);
  Res := SendMessage(HDest, WM_COPYDATA, HSource, LPARAM(@Cds));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Res));
end;

procedure TThreadCreatorForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(Self.Handle, Nil);
  Assert(ThreadID = MainThreadID);
end;

function TWndThreadWindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  pSelf: TWndThread;
  Message: TMessage;
begin
  pSelf := TWndThread(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA));
  if pSelf <> nil then
  begin
    Message.Msg := uMsg;
    Message.WParam := wParam;
    Message.LParam := lParam;
    Message.Result := 0;
    pSelf.WndProc(Message);
    Result := Message.Result;
  end else
    Result := DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;

constructor TWndThread.Create(ACreator: TForm; const Title:String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FTitle := Title;
  FCreator := ACreator;
  FillChar(FWndClass, SizeOf(FWndClass), 0);
  FWndClass.lpfnWndProc := @TWndThreadWindowProc;
  FWndClass.hInstance := HInstance;
  FWndClass.lpszClassName := scThreadClassName;
end;

procedure TWndThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  if Windows.RegisterClass(FWndClass) = 0 then Exit;
  FWnd := CreateWindow(FWndClass.lpszClassName, PChar(FTitle), WS_DLGFRAME, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, nil);
  if FWnd = 0 then Exit;
  SetWindowLongPtr(FWnd, GWL_USERDATA, ULONG_PTR(Self));

  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) and (not Terminated) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
  end;
end;

procedure TWndThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  if FWnd <> 0 then
    DestroyWindow(FWnd);
  Windows.UnregisterClass(FWndClass.lpszClassName, FWndClass.hInstance);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWndThread.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_Action1 : begin
      HandleAction1;
      Exit;
    end;
    WM_COPYDATA : begin
      if PCopyDataStruct(lParam).dwData = MY_CDS_VALUE then
      begin
        HandleCopyData(PCopyDataStruct(lParam)^);
        Exit;
      end;
    end; 
  end;

  Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TWndThread.HandleAction1;
begin
  //
end;

procedure TWndThread.HandleCopyData(const Cds: TCopyDataStruct);
var
  S: String;
begin
  if Cds.cbData > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(S, Cds.cbData div SizeOf(Char));
    CopyMemory(Pointer(S), Cds.lpData, Length(S) * SizeOf(Char));
  end;
  // use S as needed...
end;

initialization
  MY_CDS_VALUE := RegisterWindowMessage('MY_CDS_VALUE');

end.
```

Comment: Thanks.  I realised I needed to do a SendMessage, but didn't know I needed my own windows procedure (nor, as of now what it should contain but I guess I can look in the Delphi source).  What foxed me was that I send the WM_COPYDATA message in exactly the same way as my WM_Action1 one, and the GetMessage sees that latter but not the former.

Comment: You did not show how you are sending `WM_Action1` to the thread widow.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was because it seemed to be working correctly, so I thought it wasn't useful.  But now that I look more closely, I'm not so sure.

Comment: *Also, when sending WM_COPYDATA, the lpData field is expressed in bytes not in characters, so you need to take that in to account.* You mean `cbData`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I meant `lpData`, but yes, it does also apply to `cbData` as well. His code may be in D7 today, and thus uses `AnsiString`, which is 8bit. But if he ever migrated to D2009+, where `String` is 16bit, his original code that was allocating and filling `lpData` would fail.

Comment: lpData is a pointer and is not expressed in bytes. You meant cbData. I was trying to help you correct and improve your answer. The code in the question doesn't set cbData at all.

Comment: @Remy:  I'm glad you picked me up about how I send my WM_Action1.  I could have sworn (and indeed I have been) that it was using SendMessage but it was in fact PostMessage.  So I've edited the title and q text a bit so as not to mislead.  My excuse (such as it is) is that this testbed started with a windowless thread object and I was sending it actions via PostThreadMessage.  When I added the code to give it a window, I changed all of those to PostMessage, except the WM_COPYDATA one, because I'd read that it had to be sent, not posted.

Comment: Just avoid PostThreadMessage. Always send messages to windows. Read Raymond Chen on this subject.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I assume you are referring to this blog article? [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx)

Comment: @MartynA: personally, I would have kept using `PostThreadMessage()` (as long as the thread does not display any modal dialogs, it is safe to use), or at least switched to `PostMessage()`, and avoided using `WM_COPYDATA` for passing data between threads in the same app. Since `WM_COPYDATA` is a *sent* message, the caller blocks until the message is processed. If you need that blockage, it is just as easy to allocate a `struct` that has a waitable event from `CreateEvent()`, then post the `struct`, wait on the event, and then free the `struct`. You don't need an HWND for that.

Answer (score 3):

The copy data message is sent synchronously. Which means that it won't be returned by `GetMessage`.  So you'll need to supply a window procedure to process the message because sent messages are dispatched directly to the window procedure of their windows, being synchronous rather than asynchronous.

Beyond that the other problem is that you don't specify the length of the data in the copy data struct, `cbData`. That's needed when sending the message cross-thread so that the system can marshal your data.

You should set `dwData` so that the recipient can check that they are handling the intended message.

You don't need to use `GetMem` at all here, you can use the string buffer directly. A window handle is an `HWND` and not a `THandle`. A message only window would be most appropriate here.

Comment: I realised that I needed to do a SendMessage (and do, in the SendStringViaWMCopyData routine above) if only because I assumed something needs to hang onto the memory Cds uses until it's processed by the receive.  I guess I'll have to look up how to write a window procedure ...

Comment: That's easy enough. Setting `cbData` is also critical.

Comment: So is setting `dwData` as well, to differentiate between different `WM_COPYDATA` messages so you process only your own message and not accidentally process someone else's message.  The VCL, for instance, uses `WM_COPYDATA` internally.

Comment: @Remy Not as critical in terms of getting the message sent and received. And it's a pretty weak defence against accidental message processing. But yes, best to set it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Weak or not, `dwData` is the only protection offered by `WM_COPYDATA`, and *most* (but not all) implementations do use `RegisterWindowMessage()` to ensure that `dwData` is a unique value.

Comment: @Remy Using RegisterWindowMessage is a pretty neat trick. I've not encountered that before. Thanks.

Comment: @David:  I am, of course, indebted to you both.  I had better not mention where I borrowed the Cds-setting stuff from.  At least there will be something more accomplished for future seekers to find.